# How to handle spring tag's <form:checkbox> if it is not checked?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a scenario where an unchecked checkbox passes null value and therfore results in an null pointer exception. Can someone tell me how to handle form:checkbox if it is not checked?

The code in jsp is

```
<form:checkbox path="documentList[${docStatus.index}].ynChkBox" cssClass="genradio" 
value="-1" onclick="selectCheckBox(event.keyCode,this)"/>
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `Validator` interface, override the `validate()` method perform all the **validations** in the form as your spring form tags.

You have an [nice example here](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-form-validation-1.html) to validate forms.

Hope this helps !!